# I'm confused about these installation instructions for the Java Pet Store web application(highlighted)

Tags: jakarta-ee, ant, compilation

Installing the petstore from the command line using ant
Here are the instructions for building all the applications in the project under the ee5/ directory
These are the instructions for users of ant based builds. NetBeans users will have separate instructions.

1. Download and install Java 1.5.x or later
2. Download the latest public release(promoted binary bundle) of GlassFish app server, the Java EE 5 app server SDK
3. Download Ant version 1.6.5

   **4. Copy the petstore/ws/apps/petstore/build.properties.sample file to the user directory such as C:\DocumentsandSettings\myusername\build.properties  and**

   **5. Setup build.properties file. Copy build.properties.sample to the user directory such as C:\DocumentsandSettings\myusername\build.properties . Note the ".samples" extension is removed. Now Edit build.properties and change the following properties in build.properties:**

6.Set ANT_HOME and path to use ant version 1.6.5 and put ANT_HOME\bin in PATH

7.Set JAVA_HOME and JAVA_HOME\bin in PATH

Where exactly is the "user directory" ?  And what does "put ANT_HOME\bin in PATH" mean ? does it mean make a new environment variable named "ANT_HOME\bin" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user directory depends on your operating system.  On Windows it's usually something like

> C:\Documents and Settings\bill

No, you don't want to make a *new* environment variable named "ANT_HOME\bin".  You need to *add* that directory to your existing PATH environment variable.

(On Windows, click the Start menu, right click on My Computer and select Properties off the context menu.  This will open your System Properties dialog.  Go to the Advanced tab and click the Environment Variables button at the bottom to set up all the environment variables in these instructions.)